# Convert raw Ipython Notebook txt to Ipynb

Tags: python, text, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I have a textfile containing the source code for an Ipython Notebook.

How can I convert this file using Ipython / Python to an Ipython Notebook?

e.g. :

source.txt:

```
{
 "cells": [
  {
   "cell_type": "markdown",
   "metadata": {},
   "source": [
    "Test"
   ]
  },
}
...
```

The questions on SE deal with converting an actual notebook to a .py or otherwise. I'm looking just to get to the notebook in the first place.

Edit:
I'm on Mac

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to first install iPython package

```
pip install ipython
```

Save your current file as .py file using notepad++
Then try below code

```
import IPython.nbformat.current as convert
conv = convert.read(open('source.py', 'r'), 'py')
convert.write(conv, open('source.ipynb', 'w'), 'ipynb')
```

Comment: On Mac so no notepad++, got an alternative?

Comment: You can just put .py as the file extension to convert text file to Python. You don't need Notepad++. But you could also convert other file types. Using this example, I applied: ```conv = convert.read(open('source.txt', 'r'), 'txt')```

Comment: I get an error "UserWarning: nbformat.current is deprecated." Has something changed? Thank you

Comment: @Confounded No this is not an error but I think there is some issue from the IPython side and they are planning to fix it in next release. 

Just an update, this is just a warning and not an error so anyhow you don't need to worry.

Comment: As of 2024, the package import does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I found two ways to do, may this could help.

1. Using Notepad: Open the file in Notepad.
   save notepad as name.ipynb instead of name.txt

   and make "save as type" All Files(*.*) instead of Text Documents (*.txt)
2. Rename the file: Click File > Rename, change the name so that it ends with '.ipynb' behind, and click OK
   Close the file.

finally open file with your IDE or colab.

Answer (score 0):

The latest implementation without warnings:

```
import nbformat

nb = nbformat.read('<file-path-with-format>', 
                   nbformat.current_nbformat)

nbformat.write(nb, '<path-to-save>/<filename>.ipynb', 
               nbformat.NO_CONVERT)
```

If nbformat is not installed install it like below

```
pip install nbformat
```

Read more about nbformat [here](https://nbformat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=nbformat).

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same issue. It took me a while to figure it out.

Copy all of the text in the file with the .txt extension

Open your Mac launchpad and search for TextEdit (I may have installed this)

Open TextEdit and create a new file

Paste the text in the new file and go to Save

[image]

When saving the file use the screenshot settings below to save as .ipynb file extension

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Open file in Notepad ++
2. Save as python file.